# Why is this failing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm wrecking my brain trying to figure out what's wrong with this query.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        INSERT INTO ORDERS_HISTORY@' || DBLINK || '
        (ID, ITEM_ID, ITEM_DESC, QUANTITY, INSERTED_ON, INSERTED_BY)
        SELECT A.ORDER_ID, A.ITEM_ID, A.ITEM_DESC, A.QUANTITY_SOLD, SYSDATE, ''' || OS_USER || '''
        FROM ORDERS@' || DBLINK || ' A, ORDERS@APOLLO B
        WHERE A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID AND (B.INSERTED_ON >= ''' || V_DATE || ''' OR B.UPDATED_ON >= ''' || V_DATE || ''')';
```

This query is part of a procedure i'm developing to track changes in the remote ORDERS table, "synchronizing" it with an ORDERS table on another server an saving the changes to the latter in the ORDERS_HISTORY table. Thus, ORDERS@APOLLO should always be in sync with `ORDERS@' || DBLINK || '` (DB_LINK is dynamic as this should run on multiples servers) while the changes are stored in the `ORDERS_HISTORY@' || DBLINK || '` table. Both DBs run Oracle 11g.

In short, the source table is in server A, the code runs in server B and the target tables are stored in server C. A can't "talk" to C, so this is is the best i could come up with.

If i "test run" it without the dynamic sql it works fine, that is it inserts the expected number of rows (250). However when i run the procedure, and the query is ran with execute immediate, it inserts over 160k (160 thousand!!!) rows.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** V_DATE is defined as :

```
 SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2010 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

**Edit 2:** Removing the SYSDATE from the list of inserted fields reduced the number of rows to about half (around 80k). Still too much but it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this portion of building your SQL string, you are relying on implicit type conversion of a date to a string.

```
(B.INSERTED_ON >= ''' || V_DATE || ''' OR B.UPDATED_ON >= ''' || V_DATE || ''')
```

This means that the behavior depends on the current NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the session as well as on the datatype of the columns being compared to the resulting string.  When you are testing the query interactively, you are probably manually entering the date string in a format that happens to work.

I am not sure if this is the problem, but it is something I think you should eliminate as a possible source of trouble.

One approach is to make sure the conversion is explicit in both directions.  For example, assuming that `INSERTED_ON` is a date, do something like this:

```
'B.INSERTED_ON >= TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR( v_date, 'YYYYMMDD' ) || ''', ''YYYMMDD'')'
```

Another approach, which certainly makes for more readable code and may be better in other ways, is to use bind variables:

```
'B.INSERTED_ON >= :bind_date'
```

adding, at the end of the `EXECUTE` statement, a `USING` clause to provide the value that will be bound:

```
USING v_date
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Unfortunately it didnt't solve the issue :( Still getting 160k rows.

Comment: Spoke too soon... It actualy solved the problem :) Thanks again Dave.